# Plot colored map from geographic data

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, google-maps

I'm struggling to produce a map as follows:
[image]

Basically, I am using Google Map APIs (JavaScript) to visualize my data. My data contains plenty of points. Each point has coordinates (lat, lng) and a value (pollutant). I've tried to use heatmap layer in Google Map but it looks ugly compared to this image.
Here is my output using heatmap:
[image]

So my question is what software/package/library can make the first picture?
Many thanks.

Comment: @lzzy: I added the question, please remove "on hold"

Comment: Will do – but please also add the other required details (OS, price, etc. – see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185))